# Register php keeps on having connection reset error whenever trying to register

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbConnection.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Online Book Club</title>

</head>

<body>
    <form method ="post" action ="register.php">

           <?php
        //get the values from the form, using the POST method.
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $profession = $_POST['profession'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
        $country_of_residence = $_POST['country_of_residence'];
        $email = $_POST['first_name'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];


   $query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username ='$username'";
       $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) ;

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
           echo $message ="WARNING: Name already exist <br/>";
           echo $message = "<a href='register.php'>Return</a>";

        }
        else  {
        $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO user   (  first_name,last_name,profession,gender,date_of_birth,country_of_residence,em    ail,username,password)" .
                    "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$profession', '$gender', '$date_of_birth', '$country_of_residence', '$email', '$username', '$password')";
        //echo $queryInsert;
        //echo $queryInsert;
        $resultInsert = mysqli_query($link,$queryInsert); 
        header('Location: login.php');
            echo "<h3>The following user has been successfully added:    </h3>";

    }


    ?>

    Click <a href="admin.php"> here </a> to go back to the home page.
</body>
```

I have been trying to make this register php work, but somehow whenever I click enter after entering all the fields, I get this error:

> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

I have been trying to find out where has my connection gone wrong, but to no avail. Can someone give me some guidance on this?

Comment: does dbConnection.php set `$link` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting the document to the browser, so you can't use the `header` function, Try this:

```
<?php
     ob_start(); // TURN ON BUFFERING
     session_start();
     include 'dbConnection.php';
     ?>
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
     <head>
         <title>Online Book Club</title>

         </head>

         <body>
            <form method ="post" action ="register.php">

       <?php
    //get the values from the form, using the POST method.
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $profession = $_POST['profession'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
    $country_of_residence = $_POST['country_of_residence'];
    $email = $_POST['first_name'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


        $query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username ='$username'";
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) ;

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
       echo $message ="WARNING: Name already exist <br/>";
       echo $message = "<a href='register.php'>Return</a>";

    }
    else  {
    $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO user   (  first_name,last_name,profession,gender,date_of_birth,country_of_residence,em    ail,username,password)" .
                "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$profession', '$gender', '$date_of_birth', '$country_of_residence', '$email', '$username', '$password')";
    //echo $queryInsert;
    //echo $queryInsert;
    $resultInsert = mysqli_query($link,$queryInsert); 
    header('Location: login.php');
        echo "<h3>The following user has been successfully added:    </h3>";

}


?>

Click <a href="admin.php"> here </a> to go back to the home page.
</body>
<?php
    $output = ob_get_contents();  // GET THE CONTENT OF THE BUFFER
    ob_end_clean(); // Get current buffer contents and delete current output buffer
    echo $output;  // OUTPUT THE BUFFER CONTENT TO THE BROWSER
 ?>
```